# Where to Translate a few Pages

Tags: language, inline-translations, cvs

I've got a translation extension. In some files, things seem to be translated well, but some words don't change in frontend. I've also deleted cache.

In which CVS files can I translate these pages:

- POPULAR SEARCH TERMS
- CREATE NEW ACCOUNT
- CATALOG ADVANCED SEARCH
- CATALOG ADVANCED SEARCH FORM
- SHOPPING CART
- ORDERS AND RETURNS

[image]

- HEADER

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see where to translate I usually enable inline translation in

**System** > **Configuration** > **Advanced** > **Developer** > **Translate inline**

Enable it for the frontend of your store and save config. Now go to the frontend of your store and click on the little book icon that is next to the text that you wish to translate. A popup window will appear. There you will see the **Scope** for the translation, e.g. **Mage_Core** or **Mage_CatalogSearch**. This tells you in which .csv file to look for translation.

I prefer not to translate directly from the inline translation, since it will store the translation in the database (and not the .csv file). I only use it to find the right scope.

If you are using a custom theme then maybe there is a .csv file in the theme as well. Theme developers tend to place this file in

app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/locale/en_US

You may want to look there to see if you can find something like that. If this is the case then copy the file to local and create your own language folder with your translation file.

Comment: That worked, thank you. Except for Advanced Search Form fields, Orders and Returns dropdown List ("Email Address" and "ZIP Code") and See Shopping Cart - Update "-OR-" Continue Shopping. I can't select those with the Book.

Comment: You're welcome! Those parts that you can't access with the inline translation must be hard coded in the files, not following best practice.You may want to contact the developer of the extension or theme you are using and request for better translation options. They should use strings like `<?php echo $this->__('Shopping Cart') ?>`